# Why does resharper suggest "Method has async overload"

Tags: .net-core, resharper, .net-core-3.1, code-cleanup

In my code I have the following bit of code:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder))
{
    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'");
    bmaSerializer.Serialize(writer, startSequenceData);
    result.StartSequenceData = builder.ToString();
}
```

And I get a suggestion (from resharper) to change this line:

```
writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'");
```

Into this:

```
await writer.WriteProcessingInstructionAsync("xml", "version='1.0'");
```

But I don't understand why that would be better. Does anyone know the reasoning behind this? Is there a resource where I can check the reasoning for this and other suggestions?

Comment: It depends on how big your data. If data is big it will work, but if you have several lines you don' t need it. And this resource doesn't give any recomendations about learning courses, books and so on. You should ask a concrete question and post all data and code you have.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ and then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await